# Consulta con sed bash script string

Tags: string, bash, script, sed

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
cat test.txt
```

Que muestra lo siguiente:

> **juan maria juan maria juan maria maria juan maria juan maria juan
>   roberto roberto roberto roberto roberto roberto**

Para separar de 2 en 2 cada cadena lo hago mediante un bucle `for`, pero para resumirles, si uso:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/../& /g'
```

Obtengo la siguiente salida:

> **ju an  m ar ia  ma ri a  ju an  ro be rt o  ro be rt o**

¿Cómo hago con `sed` para que no le importen los repetidos?

Saludos

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado que esperas

Comment: no queda claro cuál es el objetivo de la tarea. ¿Podrías darle a [edit] y añadir detalles para que sea útil para la próxima gente que entre por aquí?

Answer (score 2):

Lo solucioné temporalmente haciendo lo sigueinte:

sed estaba tomándome los espacios vacíos:

```
temp="0001 0002 0001 0002 0001 0002"
echo $temp | grep -v " " | sed 's/../& /g'
00 01  0 00 2  00 01  0 00 2  00 01  0 00 2
```

Con tr -d como delimitador:

```
echo $temp | tr -d " " | sed 's/../& /g'
00 01 00 02 00 01 00 02 00 01 00 02
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva.

Comment: Buen uso de sed :)

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo con tr es borrar los espacios